# How to save data to mysql server with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am currently trying to build an application for my project. 
It is my first time programming as well as using node.js
I have successfully connected node.js with mysql and was able to save data to mysql server. 
**However, some data that I want to save is declared as undefined**

currently my code looks like this

imap.once('ready', function() {

```
openInbox(function(err, box) {

    if (err) throw err;
    imap.search([ 'UNSEEN', ['SINCE', 'December 20, 2018'] ], function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('you are already up to date');
        }
        //var f = imap.fetch(results, {markSeen: true, bodies: ''});
        var f = imap.fetch(results, {bodies: ''});
        f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
            var prefix = '(#' + seqno + ') ';

            msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {

              simpleParser(stream, (err, mail) => {
                con.connect(function(err) {
                  console.log("Connected!");
                  var sql = "INSERT INTO scrap (reply_to, content) VALUES ('" + mail.from.text + "', '" + mail.subject +"')";
                  con.query(sql, function (err , result) {

                  });
                });
                console.log(mail.from);
                // console.log(mail.from.text);
                // console.log(mail.subject);
                // console.log(mail.text);


              });
```

the Console.log will fetch information like this

{ value:
   [ { address: 'xxx@gmail.com', name: 'NAME' } ],
  html:
   'NAME <xxx@gmail.com>',
  text: 'NAME ' }

I would like to know how to fetch email and name separately.
I have tried console.log(mail.from.address) or (mail.from.mailto) but it returns **undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
mail.from.value[0].address  // fetch email
mail.from.value[0].name //fetch name
```

Comment: if you find this anwer was helpful please vote it and mark it as the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Can I ask you to explain what .value[0] means? or any link that might help me study mysql with node.js?

Comment: its not  mysql mate.. Ita arrays you shoud study here as you can see it gives you an array of objects.. so what I have done is accessing that array using []. [0] means the first index of that array